# Does one still need exclusive access to retrieve shelveset while offline

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, shelveset, unshelve

I shelved some changes in TFS (2013) last night. Now I am working offline and I want to retreive that shelveset. TFS whines saying that the file is checked out by someone.

I dont understand this. I am working offline and I want a specific version of a file. Why should I/TFS care about other changes?

Or, is there some configuration or action that I need to do?

Comment: Shelvesets are stored on the server.  How are you unshelving if you are offline?

Comment: Shelved it before going offline. Anyways, turns out TFS first restores the shelveset.

Answer (score 1):

YES!

Found the answer in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404(v=vs.100).aspx):

> When you unshelve a shelveset, Team Foundation restores each shelved revision to the destination workspace as a pending change as long as the revision does not conflict with a change that is already pending in the workspace.